# Some Analysis Problems

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Some one told me that the functions

$f(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ are lines Passing through origins.

And the problem is about, With out pointing out the notion of continuity at least at one point can we conclude what he said?

I can prove this using continuity at least at one point ..!!

Any Hints or solutions are welcomed

Comment: The "lines" part is false when $f$ is discontinuous.

Comment: The proof requires continuity at one point. There are everywhere discontinuous counterexamples (assuming the axiom of choice). You can read about it by googling "Cauchy functional equation" and "hamel basis"

Comment: I shouldn't say "requires continuity at one point". But it requires some niceness assumption about $f$.

Comment: With the axiom of choice, there are functions satisfying the Cauchy condition without being continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article
on
Cauchy's functional equation:

Any of the following conditions
are sufficient to make
the only solutions
lines through the origin:

f is monotonic on any interval.

f is bounded on any interval.

f is Lebesgue measurable.

So any nonlinear solution
is very unruly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider vector space $V=R$ with field $Q$,  rational number. One can show that $V$ is an infinite dimensional vector space ! Consider usual topology on R.

Then $V$ is an infinite dimensional normed vector space, so there is a linear function on $V$ say $f: R \to R$ which is not continuous !

Since $f$ is linear we have $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) $ but $f$ is not continuous so it is not a line !